# How to build an image from Dockerfile using Earthly target?

Tags: earthly

I would like to build and image from `Dockerfile` using Earthly.
You might be wondering why do I want that, because I can describe images right inside of `Earthfile`, but I have 2 reasons for using external `Dockerfile`:

1. `ADD` command (which I need to download file by URL) is [not supported](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/earthfile#add-not-supported) by Earthly yet
2. I would like to use a [heredoc syntax](https://www.docker.com/blog/introduction-to-heredocs-in-dockerfiles/) for embedding file's content into container right from `Dockerfile`. This requires `# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4`, which is again not available in `Earthfile`

So, here is what I tried to do.

My approximate `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java17:nonroot
WORKDIR /opt/app
ADD --chown=nonroot https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/releases/download/3.4.7/applicationinsights-agent-3.4.7.jar agent.jar
COPY <<EOF /opt/app/applicationinsights.json
{
  "instrumentation": {}
}
EOF
```

And this is how I try to build it with `Earthly`:

```
base-image:
    FROM earthly/dind:alpine
    WORKDIR /build
    ENV DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 # <---- required to support heredoc syntax
    COPY distroless-runtime-17.Dockerfile Dockerfile
    WITH DOCKER --allow-privileged
        RUN docker build . -t base-17-image
    END
```

While the `WITH DOCKER RUN` part gets executed successfully, I do not know how to use the result of `base-image` target in other targets to package my app using the resulting base image. The `FROM base-17-image` just fails as if it does not exist (and this tag really does not exist - `docker run base-17-image` fails with the same reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [turned out](https://earthly.dev/faq#build) to be very easy and [natively supported](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/earthfile#from-dockerfile):

The whole recipe is just 2 lines of code:

```
base-image:
    FROM DOCKERFILE -f distroless-runtime-17.Dockerfile .
```

and the result can of the above step can be reused to package your application as: `FROM +base-image`